# Swift - function inside function?

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

Following the wonderful post about [IBInspectable / IBDesignable](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/), I am reading the [example code](https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/4269059121ec247fbb90) and can't understand how function drawRect contains another functions. Can somebody explain?

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    ....

    func rectForPosition(position: CGPoint, andSize size: CGSize) -> CGRect
    {
       ....     
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: What is it that you don't understand, exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968133/what-is-the-practical-use-of-nested-functions-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the benefit of nesting functions (in general/in Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354534/what-is-the-benefit-of-nesting-functions-in-general-in-swift)

Comment: A function declared in the body of a function (also called a local function) is available to be called by later code within the same scope, but is completely invisible elsewhere. -- Matt Neuburg, IOS 10 Programming Fundamentals with Swift (Third edition), p.41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rectForPosition` is a function declared in scope of `drawRect`. Same as with variables, that means that `rectForPosition` is visible and usable only inside of `drawRect`.

Since as per [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351) function declaration contains statements:

> ```
> func function name(parameters) {
>      statements
> }
> ```

And a statement can be a declaration:

> statement → declaration­

It is a valid Swift code.